# Knockout select options and dependencies

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a select list and I want to change the visibility of different divs depending on the selection.

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: conditions">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $parent.conditionTypes, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: type"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div data-bind="visible: $parent.isGroupCondition($data)">
                    Group list
                </div>
                <div data-bind="visible: $parent.isTagCondition($data)">
                    Tag list
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $parent.conditionOperations, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: operation"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-bind="attr: {value: value}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCondition.bind($parent)">remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried to use the event binding "event: {change: $parent.conditionTypeChanged}" but I'm not sure how to trigger the div's bindings to fire.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/370t02nt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to make your `type` property [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) in the items in the `conditions`

```
conditions: ko.observableArray([{type: ko.observable(1), operation: 1, value: 'test'}]),
```

And use the observable in your `isGroupCondition` and `isTagCondition` functions:

```
isGroupCondition: function (condition) {
    return condition.type() === 2;
},
isTagCondition: function (condition) {
    return condition.type() === 1;
},
```

because your `type` is now an observable Knockout will take care updating the visibility bindings and hide/show your divs.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pn33yca/).

Comment: Thanks! ;) That actually just dawned on me right before I saw your answer